# Create a Sql Azure Database with serverless tier using SDK

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

Currently, I create databases and attach them to an SQL elastic pool:

```
database = await sqlServer.Databases.Define(mainDb.DbName).WithExistingElasticPool(pool.Name).CreateAsync();
```

Instead, I want to create databases with tier "General Purpose: Serverless, Gen5, 1 vCore", but I couldn't find any method that offers that possibility.

This feature is still in preview, I can't find anything on the forums on this. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I know how to create a Serverless with PowerShell. Do you want me to provide that as possible answer with an example?

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo For powershell it's in the official docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-serverless#use-powershell , but I'm looking for the c# sdk way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following c# code to create "General Purpose: Serverless, Gen5, 1 vCore" database

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(client,key,tenant,AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription(SubscriptionId);
var sqlserver=azure.SqlServers.GetById("/subscriptions/<your subscrption id>/resourceGroups/<your resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<your server name>");
var database = sqlserver.Databases.Define("test").WithEdition("GeneralPurpose").WithServiceObjective("GP_S_Gen5_1").Create();
Console.WriteLine(database.ServiceLevelObjective);
Console.WriteLine(database.Edition);
Console.WriteLine(database.Name);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to @`Jim Xu` accepted answer, the API has changed.

`var database = sqlserver.Databases.Define("test").WithEdition("GeneralPurpose").WithServiceObjective("GP_S_Gen5_1").Create();`

The `WithEdition` is now a `DatabaseEdition` edition type, and `WithServiceObjective` is now a `ServiceObjectiveName`. Both of these are muddled string enums with lists of version types. They do both also accept a `.Parse()` method. So the line should now be:

```
var database = sqlserver.Databases.Define("test")
             .WithEdition(**Database.Edition.Parse("GeneralPurpose")**)
             .WithServiceObjective(**ServiceObjectiveName.Parse("GP_S_Gen5_1")**)
             .Create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this tutorial: [Create a new elastic database pool with C#](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool-create-csharp.md#create-a-new-elastic-database-pool-with-c).

It provides the code example about [Create a new database in a pool](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool-create-csharp.md#create-a-new-database-in-a-pool):

Create a `DataBaseCreateorUpdateProperties` instance, and set the properties of the new database. Then call the `CreateOrUpdate` method with the resource group, server name, and new database name.

```
// Create a database: configure create or update parameters and properties explicitly
DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters newPooledDatabaseParameters = new DatabaseCreateOrUpdateParameters()
{
    Location = currentServer.Location,
    Properties = new DatabaseCreateOrUpdateProperties()
    {
        Edition = "Standard",
        RequestedServiceObjectiveName = "ElasticPool",
        ElasticPoolName = "ElasticPool1",
        MaxSizeBytes = 268435456000, // 250 GB,
        Collation = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    }
};

var poolDbResponse = sqlClient.Databases.CreateOrUpdate("resourcegroup-name", "server-name", "Database2", newPooledDatabaseParameters);
```

Please try to replace "`standard`" with the price tier "`General Purpose: Serverless, Gen5, 1 vCore`".

Hope this helps.